# Javascript Table Iteration

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an x-y table called "num", and I am trying to iterate through the table and obtain the numerical values in the cells. The alert keep showing me "undefined", and I don't know why. I've tried the innerHTML function, but it doesn't give me the value I need. Any help would be appreciated (I'm new to Javascript).

```
 var x=0;
 var y=0;
 var table=document.getElementById("num");

    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {

        x= table.rows[r].cells[0].value;
        y= table.rows[r].cells[1].value;
        alert(x);

    }
```

Comment: table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML works,  see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_cells_index

Answer (score 1):

```
> x= table.rows[r].cells[0].value
```

Table cells (td and th elements) don't have a default *value* property. If you wish to get the text content of a DOM element, you can use the [W3C *textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) property or the [IE *innerText*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property depending on which one is supported in the host. Browsers support one or the other, some both, so you can do:

```
var cell;
...
cell = table.rows[r].cells[0];
x = cell.textContent || cell.innerText;
```

You can also write a small function to do the job:

```
function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;
  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
x = getText(table.rows[r].cells[0]);
```

Note that the value of *x* will be a string, so be careful if you intend using the `+` operator for addition.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want `.innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

`.value` is for form elements like inputs.

Comment: I wasn't clear; the table has input boxes of type "number". When I change it to innerText, nothing appears in the alert

Comment: `.value` only works for the inputs (and form elements), not other dom elements. If you use inputs, you need `.value` but you need to find the input, not the `td` element